# Is it possible to use JQuery to load a url into an iframe when a link is clicked on the same page?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Is is possible using JQuery to load the src of an `<a>` tag into an iframe on the same page as the linked clicked if you can not edit the html?

Something similar to this but instead of getting the value from the input the src value would be the src of the link the person clicks on?

http://jsfiddle.net/kbwood/DLprk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$('#url').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#display').attr('src', $('#url').attr('href'));
});
```

```css
iframe { width: 100%; height: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="display"></iframe>
<br>
    <a type="text" id="url" href="http://jquery.com">test</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Leeish for your quick answer and example. This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I will mark this as accepted as soon as it allows me. +1 checked

Comment: If you can edit the HTML, @ncardeli has the better answer as it's HTML only.

Answer (score 4):

That's what [target attribute](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/target-html-attribute/) is for.

```css
iframe { width: 100%; height: 50%; }
```

```html
<iframe id="display" name="display"></iframe>
<br>
    <a href="http://jquery.com" target="display">Load</a>
```

Comment: That's far too simple. :) Granted his answer requested jQuery. But the target attribute would be the "best" solution assuming he can edit the HTML.

Comment: Thank you this also would work. There is a larger JQuery function that runs with the page that I wanted to add the functionality to. +1

Comment: @Denoteone, as Leeish points out, if you can edit the HTML, this is the best solution as it doesn't require any Javascript code, which makes it SEO friendly and accesible.

Comment: @Denoteone If your question is not about `<a>` tags, you really should rephrase it (for future visitors).

Comment: I updated the title of the question to better reflect what I was looking for in this specific case.